# what can I use insead putPixel method

Tags: java

I would like to draw line using Bresenham Algorithm but I have problem. I dont know, what should I use instead `putPixel()` method in my code:

```
public void Line(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1){

    int deltaX = x1-x0;
    int deltaY = y1-y0;

    double error = 0;
    double realError = deltaY/(double) deltaX;

    double j = y0;
    for(int i = x0; i<= x1; i++){
        putpixel(i,(int)j);
        j += realError;
    }

}
```

All tutorials have `putpixel()` method. What can I use instead of this method?

Comment: why exactly don't you want to use `putPixel()`?

Comment: @MrD Well, because there is no `putPixel()`. Or is it?

Comment: @MrD - how should code definition of putPixel() method should look like?

Comment: lol should have checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method in Java (awt or Swing) that deliberately paints a single pixel.

You need to use one of these:

- [`drawLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with starting and final coordinates equal to each other
- [`fillRect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) with `width` and `length` equal to `1`.

Or draw the line as an image, if that's plausible for you. You could use [`BufferedImage#setRGB()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int%29).